# Problem in sound in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound

two days ago I opened a video using Videos and it said that I need to download some kind of plugin to be able to play the movie, I have downloaded it.
Now the sound in every video on my machine is corrupted and I can hear nothing but noise when I play sound files on the machine, although the test sound in the settings sections is clear, and I am not able to make any skype call as well.